# JavaScript subtract time in moment used in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I am using **React Js** and I would like to perform a subtract time in **JavaScript** with *moment* library.

I tried my code as follows:

```
timecheck(){
    var time1 = moment().format("09:00:00");
    var time2 = moment().format("00:03:15");
    var timeStr = time2.split(':');
    var h = timeStr[0];
    var m = timeStr[1];
    var s = timeStr[2];

    var time3 = moment(time1).subtract({'hours': h, 'minutes': m, 'second': s}).format('hh:mm:ss');
    console.log(time3);
  }
```

The above code was my `timecheck` function, I would like to perform `time3 = time1 - time2`, it console log as `InvalidDate`

May I know where is my syntax error?

Comment: whats your expected output after subtraction ?

Comment: Hi @AlwaysHelping I would like to have 'hh:mm:ss' format

Comment: I understand that! But whats your final time expected out after subtraction ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping so it is 9h minus 3 minutes 15 seconds it will be 8h : 56min : 45sec something like that or '08:56:45'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use `.subtract` function to do get the results you are after. You do not need to use `split` or anything like that!

Also, we need define the `format` of our times we are subtracting from as `hh:mm:ss` in the `moment` object otherwise you will get a `deprecation` warning.

```js
let time1 = moment("09:00:00", "hh:mm:ss");
let time2 = moment("00:03:15", "hh:mm:ss");
let subtract = time1.subtract(time2);
let format = moment(subtract).format("hh:mm:ss")
console.log(format); //08:56:45
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yup, the solution works, however I am not sure why I get `04:26:45` instead of `08:56:45`

Comment: @Lawraoke really! in my answer its `08:56:45` which is correct! Are you sure you are doing the right times ?

Comment: yes that is why I am not sure why is the answer difference :(, however, I run your code snippet it is `08:56:45`, while I try on my js file, it went `04:26:45` but it is ok, I will sort out the rest :)

Comment: @Lawraoke thats is very weird. I am guessing you have some define some sort of timezone in your react JS app - which is overriding this calculations. Its definitely something with your react app. Otherwise the snippet would show wrong results in your browser too.

Comment: `let format = moment.utc(subtract).format("hh:mm:ss")` treat it as UTC

Comment: @Kalhan.Toress thanks! i was going to add `.utc` thing just now

Comment: @Lawraoke try using this in your react code => `let format = moment.utc(subtract).format("hh:mm:ss")` - i am sure this is something to do with server time or else.

Comment: Yep it is the UTC problem, wow great thanks for solving my question! :)

Comment: @AlwaysHelping that is another question of mine, not relevant to this question, are you happen to know about `moment` time comparison too? For example time1 < time2 something like that, or I just if(time1 < time2) will do?

Comment: @Lawraoke Yes. But there is `neat` and simple solution for that too. You can use 
moment functions like `isBefore` or `isAfter` to check whether `onetime` is greater then the other one (comparison). Hope this helps.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping ok let me dig more into that! Thanks again :D

Answer (score 2):

```
    const time1 = moment("09:00:00", 'hh:mm:ss'); //create the first time
    const time2 = moment("00:03:15", 'hh:mm:ss'); //create the second time

    const hours = time1.diff(time2, 'hours'); //Get the hours diff and set the hours for second date
    time2.add(hours, 'hours');

    const minutes = time1.diff(time2, 'minutes');
    time2.add(minutes, 'minutes');

    const seconds = time1.diff(time2, 'seconds');
    time2.add(seconds, 'seconds');

    // Get the differences
    const diff = [
        hours,
        minutes,
        seconds
    ];

    // Get the diff as a string
    const time3 = moment(diff, 'hh:mm:ss').format('hh:mm:ss');
    console.log(time3);
```

Comment: Thats a-lot more complicated solution this can simply be done using `subtract` function. See my answer below => simple `two` lines of code!

Answer (score 1):

I notice that your `h`, `m`, and `s` variables are strings rather than numbers. You seem to want numbers rather than strings.
Try something like

```
var h = timeStr[0] - 0;
```

or whatever is your favorite way of coercing a string to a numeric value.

Comment: So I am missing parse int here?

Comment: You could use `parseInt`. Remember to specify base 10, thus: `var h = parseInt(timestr[0], 10);`

Answer (score 1):

Moment has a difference function:

```
var time1 = moment("09:00:00", "hh:mm:ss");
var time2 = moment("00:03:15", "hh:mm:ss");
var diff = time2.diff(time1);
```

`diff` will be the number of milliseconds between the two date. So then it should just be a case of:

```
var time3 = moment(diff).format('hh:mm:ss');
```

See https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/ for more details.

Comment: This is not a working solution below. Please check your code! It will throw an error. Just FYI

Comment: Thank you - error fixed. The solution is above your comment. Just FYI